# Issue occurred while installing Oracle 8i

Tags: windows-7, installation, database

I am trying to install Oracle 8i but during installation it found an error of jrew.exe file. Oracle 8i was not installed on my computer. I try to install the Oracle product from the CD. So what can I do to install this product?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 8.1 is not supported on Windows 7. It was never intended to be used on Windows 7. You may use a virtualization software like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [VMware](http://vmware.com/products/server/overview.html).

Oracle 8i went [EOL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_8i) in 2006. You might want to look at [10g Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/102xewinsoft-090667.html) or [11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) for your needs.

Comment: @Sathya: Thanks for correcting my teeny tiny typo :)

Comment: No worries @Mehper :)